# How to iterate two foreach loops one by one

Tags: php, arrays

I am getting data into two arrays and i want to push that data into single array one by one. Let say i want to get first element from first array and first element from second array and then push that data into single array.

first array

```
$url = $a->attr['href'];
$lnk[] = ['url'=>$url];
```

second array

```
$img = $img->attr['src'];
$img[] = ['img'=>$img];
```

I want this

```
$data[] = ['url'=>$url, 'img'=>$img];
```

Comment: What is `$a` and `$img`? Btw you overwrite `$img` first with attribute value next with array.

Comment: Would [`array_merge()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) work for you?

Comment: Sory array_merge will not work for me

Answer (score 1):

I assume the size is same so you can iterate over the length on any of the arrays.

```
$finalArray=[];
for($i=0;$i<count($lnk);$i++){
   $finalArray[] = ['url'=>$lnk[$i]['url'], 'img'=>$img[$i]['img']];
}
```

Comment: that's what I wrote in the first row and it's same as per the OP given description, that's exactly why the images and links are kept together.

Comment: @HabibUrRehman mark it as answered if that solved your problem. Thanks